# Do I need web.config for non-ASCII characters?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, encoding, utf-8

Attempting to make my first ASP.NET page. Got IIS 5.1 on XP, configured to run .NET 4. Created a new virtual directory and added an .aspx file. When I browse the file, non-ASCII characters are corrupted. For instance, an ü (U+00FC) is transformed to Ã¼ (U+00C3 U+00BC), which is the I-don't-get-this-is-UTF-8 equivalent.

I have tried various ways of availing this:

1. I made sure the .aspx file is indeed encoded as UTF-8.
2. I set the meta tag:

   `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
3. I set the virtual directory to handle .aspx as `text/html;charset=utf-8` under HTTP Headers > File Type in IIS.
4. I added `ResponseEncoding="utf-8"` to `<%@ Page ... %>`.
5. I inserted the string in `HttpUtility.HtmlEncoded()`. Now the ü was transformed to Ã¼ (U+00C3 U+00BC).

Finally, I found 2 ways that worked:

1. Replacing non-ASCII characters with character references, such as `&#252;` This was okay in the 90's, not today.
2. Adding a web.config file to the virtual directory, with this content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.web>
       <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8"/>
     </system.web>
   </configuration>
   ```

Without `fileEncoding` setting, the ASP.NET parser will read the .aspx and corrupt every non-ASCII character without attempting to infer the file encoding. Is this just something you pros have learned to live with, or am I missing something? Is a web.config file with globalization settings *the* way to handle "international" characters on .aspx pages? I don't remember having similar problems with PHP, so I'm puzzled why this crops up with ASP.NET.

Comment: I found another way of making it work without the web.config file: Save the .aspx page as UTF-8 with byte-order-mark (BOM). In general, UTF-8 shouldn't need a BOM, since the byte-order is implicit in the encoding, but Microsoft have a tradition to require it, which is probably the right thing to do, since it makes inferring the file encoding more robust. I guess this is the kind of solution I was looking for, but comments are still welcome.

Comment: You should consider installing Microsoft Web platform installer and using IIS express 7.5 and web matrix or VS 2010 express

Answer (score 4):

To use non-ASCII characters you need to have two things. Save the files using UTF-8, by choosing this encoding for the files and be sure that you have these settings on your **web.config**

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"  fileEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Note that there is always a web.config on ASP.NET. There is the global one that also has these settings and lives in the asp.net directory `{drive:}\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{version}\CONFIG\`, and then the web.config on your project. Sometimes the global one sets the encoding from the current country. In this case you need to set it back to UTF-8 in your project.

You have found all that already, I just point out the 3 settings:

1. Save your files with unicode.
2. Set the requestEncoding="utf-8"
3. Set the responseEncoding="utf-8"

Comment: this didnt worked. after i added fileEncoding it worked. 
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8"  />

Answer (score 0):

You have three options.

Option 1 - either entity-encode all characters that don't fit into ASCII or replace them with similarly looking ASCII equivalents. This is error-prone and hard to maintain. The next time you have to incorporate a large piece of text you may forget to check the included piece and it "looks garbage" again.

Option 2 - save the .aspx as "UTF-8 with BOM". Such files are properly handled automatically - that's documented in description of `fileEncoding` property of `system.web/globalization` section of web.config. This is also hard to maintain - the next time you get the file resaved as "UTF-8" (without BOM) it "looks garbage" again and it may go unnoticed. When you add new .aspx files you'll have to check they are saved as "UTF-8 with BOM" too. This approach is error prone - for example, some file comparison tools don't show adding/removing BOM (at least with default settings).

Option 3 - ensure the file is saved as either "UTF-8" or "UTF-8 with BOM" and at the same time set `fileEncoding` property of `system.web/globalization` section of web.config to `utf-8`. The default value of this property is "single byte character encoding" so files with non-ASCII character saved as UTF-8 are handled improperly and result "looks garbage". This is the most maintainable approach - it's easy to see and easy to verify and don't randomly break when a file is resaved. `fileEncoding` is the only one of the three `???Encoding` properties which defaults to "single byte character encoding" - `responseEncoding` and `requestEncoding` default to `utf-8` so in most cases there's no need to change (or set) them, setting `fileEncoding` is usually enough.