# IIS7 doesn't redirect to index in localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, coldfusion

I've installed Coldfusion 11 locally (IIS7 Handler mappings for cfc,cfm,cfml,cfr,cfsw are all there) and when I type the full address to my index page there are no problems for the page to load:

http://localhost:8080/mysite/index.cfm

but when I simply input: http://localhost:8080/mysite/

I get the following error:

================================

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not determine which version of ASP.NET Web Pages to use.

In order to use this site, specify a version in the site’s web.config file. For more information, see the following article on the Microsoft support site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254126
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not determine which version of ASP.NET Web Pages to use.

In order to use this site, specify a version in the site’s web.config file. For more information, see the following article on the Microsoft support site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254126

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

=================================

EDIT: I've tested replacing my index.cfm with index.html and I still get the same error.

Comment: Make sure `index.cfm` is at the top of the list of default documents for that IIS site.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten it already is.

Comment: Does the server recognize other index files like .html?

Comment: @cfqueryparam No, It doesn't. So I removed my index.cfm and replaced it with index.html and I still get the same error.

Comment: @user3376065 Well, that shows that CF and the CF handlers aren't the root of the problem. I found a question and answer that might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657177/can-i-use-asp-net-web-pages-without-deploying-the-bin-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out, by mistake there was an .cshtml copied in the wwwroot folder of my web server which caused this error. I deleted it and now all my sites are functioning correctly.